# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' when using Google Translate API in Python

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator

root = Tk()
root.title("Google Translator")
root.geometry("1080x400")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.configure(background="white")

def label_change():
    c = combo1.get()
    c1 = combo2.get()
    label1.configure(text=c)
    label2.configure(text=c1)
    root.after(1000, label_change)

def translate_now():
    text_= text1.get(1.0, END)
    t1 = Translator(service_urls=['translate.google.com'])
    trans_text = t1.translate(text_, src=combo1.get(), dest=combo2.get())
    trans_text = trans_text.text

    text2.delete(1.0, END)
    text2.insert(END, trans_text)

language = googletrans.LANGUAGES
languageV = list(language.values())
lang1 = language.keys()

#combobox1
combo1 = ttk.Combobox(root, values=languageV, font="Roboto 14", state="r")
combo1.place(x=110, y=20)
combo1.set("ENGLISH")

label1 = Label(root, text="ENGLISH", font="seoge 30 bold", bg="white", width=18, bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
label1.place(x=10, y=50)

#combobox2
combo2 = ttk.Combobox(root, values=languageV, font="Roboto 14", state="r")
combo2.place(x=730, y=20)
combo2.set("SELECT LANGUAGE")

label2 = Label(root, text="ENGLISH", font="seoge 30 bold", bg="white", width=18, bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
label2.place(x=620, y=50)

#frame1
f = Frame(root, bg="Black", bd=5)
f.place(x=10, y=118, width=440, height=210)
text1 = Text(f, font="Roboto 20", bg="white", relief=GROOVE, wrap=WORD)
text1.place(x=0, y=0, width=430, height=200)

scrollbar1 = Scrollbar(f)
scrollbar1.pack(side="right", fill='y')

scrollbar1.configure(command=text1.yview)
text1.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar1.set)

#frame2
f1 = Frame(root, bg="Black", bd=5)
f1.place(x=620, y=118, width=440, height=210)
text2 = Text(f1, font="Roboto 20", bg="white", relief=GROOVE, wrap=WORD)
text2.place(x=0, y=0, width=430, height=200)

scrollbar2 = Scrollbar(f1)
scrollbar2.pack(side="right", fill='y')

scrollbar2.configure(command=text2.yview)
text2.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar2.set)

#translate button
translate = Button(root, text="Translate", font=("Roboto", 15), activebackground="white", cursor="hand2", bd=1,
                   width=10, height=2, bg="black", fg="white", command=translate_now)
translate.place(x=476, y=250)

label_change()
root.mainloop()
```

I am facing exception in this code. Exception is
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1921, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
File "/tmp/ipykernel_5269/225256526.py", line 22, in translate_now
trans_text = t1.translate(text_, src=combo1.get(), dest=combo2.get())
File "/home/zain/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googletrans/client.py", line 182, in translate
data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
File "/home/zain/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googletrans/client.py", line 78, in _translate
token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
File "/home/zain/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googletrans/gtoken.py", line 194, in do
self._update()
File "/home/zain/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googletrans/gtoken.py", line 62, in _update
code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

I need anyone to solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems here
A new alpha version of google translate was released with a fix for this issue
Install that version with this command

```
pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0
```

Also, change this in your translate_now function
This

```
t1 = Translator(service_urls=['translate.google.com'])
```

To

```
t1 = Translator()
```

This.

Comment: Thanks bro!
It works but there is one problem. As I translate English word into Urdu, It is not joining the urdu letters. 
For Example,
English: Brave  into Urdu: بہادر